# WPF and MDI model

Tags: c#, wpf

After many years of Windows Forms development, i decided to experiment with WPF. In the company i work for, i have built a great amount of software based on the MDI style and i would like to continue to do so when using WPF.

I know that MDI is not "supported" my WPF and i am trying to find a work around this matter. I also know that i can mimic MDI behavior by the WPF tab control but this is not an optimal solution for me.

Users here, are used to have software with an MDI form and many forms underneath that serve as monitoring different tasks, asynchronously, and being always visible.

Is there any way i can achieve this functionality in WPF without Tab or using 3rd party controls and without some kine of WinForms interop ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the following project:
http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/

Other option is to make something yourself, which allows for interesting stuff relating to multimonitor behaviour etc..

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was aware of this project but i would rather not using another control/library to do that. I was hoped for a way to do it by using only the framework and nothing else, i.e., hoping for some kind of wpf- trick that i am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I have built MDI for WPF using functionality of Popup control. I suggest you do not use common  win forms way which based on separate controls, but use MVVM for WPF.
So, each MDI window is Popup which wraps a view model. Application itself is base window which hosts view models and operates with windows via view models.

I provide a real life MDI window sample. Be aware that this is not complete sample, but it is enought to demonstrate some basic conceptions. All necessary classes are custom, so no dependency from the third part components:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Pane}">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="uiFreePaneTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Popup  
                x:Name="PART_DRAG" HorizontalOffset="{Binding X}" VerticalOffset="{Binding Y}"
                IsOpen="{Binding IsOpened}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                AllowsTransparency="True">
                <Border 
                    Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" 
                    BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Margin="0" CornerRadius="5" 
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                    Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}">
                    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Resizer}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!--Pane header-->
                            <Thumb  Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Height="21">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragDelta">
                                        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DragCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <Thumb.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <Grid.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0C286C" Offset="1"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Grid.Background>

                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" />

                                            <Button Template="{StaticResource CloseButton}" 
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                Margin="1,1,3,1" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}">
                                <!--Pane content-->
                                <AdornerDecorator>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                </AdornerDecorator>

                                <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    IsTabStop="false"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </DataTemplate.Resources>

    <ContentControl x:Name="uiBorder" Content="{Binding Model}" />

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFree}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="uiBorder" Property="ContentControl.Template" Value="{StaticResource uiFreePaneTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>        
</DataTemplate>
```

View model:

```
public class Pane : HideableChildViewModel, IPane
{
    private IViewModel _model;
    private bool _isFree = true;
    private string _name;
    private double _coordinateX;
    private double _coordinateY;
    private double _width = 200.0;
    private double _height = 400.0;

    private ICommand _closeCommand;
    private ICommand _dragCommand;
    private ICommand _resizeCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Pane class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">The parent view model</param>
    /// <param name="parentPropertySelector">Selector of the parent property</param>
    /// <param name="model">VM to place within the pane</param>
    public Pane(
        IViewModel parent, 
        Expression<Func<object>> parentPropertySelector,
        IViewModel model)
        : base(parent, parentPropertySelector)
    {
        this.Model = model;

        this._dragCommand = new DragPaneCommand();
        this._resizeCommand = new ResizeCommand();
        if (model != null && model is ICloseableVM)
        {
            this._closeCommand = new ClosePaneCommand();
        }
        else
        {
            this._closeCommand = new HideCommand();
        }
    }

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets VM to place within the pane
    /// </summary>
    public IViewModel Model
    {
        get 
        {
            return this._model; 
        }

        set 
        {
            if (this._model != value)
            {
                this._model = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Model);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets name of the pane
    /// </summary>
    [LayoutSettings(IsKey = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get 
        {
            return this._name; 
        }

        set 
        {
            if (this._name != value)
            {
                this._name = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets X coordinate
    /// </summary>
    [LayoutSettings]
    public double X
    {
        get 
        {
            return this._coordinateX; 
        }

        set 
        {
            if (this._coordinateX != value)
            {
                this._coordinateX = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.X);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Y coordinate
    /// </summary>
    [LayoutSettings]
    public double Y
    {
        get 
        {
            return this._coordinateY; 
        }

        set 
        {
            if (this._coordinateY != value)
            {
                this._coordinateY = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Y);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets width
    /// </summary>
    [LayoutSettings]
    public double Width
    {
        get
        {
            return this._width;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._width != value)
            {
                this._width = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Width);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets height
    /// </summary>
    [LayoutSettings]
    public double Height
    {
        get
        {
            return this._height;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._height != value)
            {
                this._height = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Height);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether pane is free
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsFree
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isFree;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._isFree != value)
            {
                this._isFree = value;
                this.OnIsFreeChanged(this._isFree);
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IsFree);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets command for pane closing
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand CloseCommand
    {
        get { return this._closeCommand; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets command for pane dragging
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand DragCommand
    {
        get { return this._dragCommand; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets command for pane resize
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand ResizeCommand
    {
        get { return this._resizeCommand; }
    }

    #endregion

    private void OnIsFreeChanged(bool isFree)
    {
        if (!isFree)
        {
            return;
        }

        IDockContainer oContainer = ((IChildViewModel)((IChildViewModel)this.Parent).Parent).Parent as IDockContainer;
        if (oContainer != null)
        {
            this.SetParent(oContainer, () => oContainer.FreeItems);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Pavel, thanks for the (detailed) answer. I have to carefully study your solution before i go that path. I understand that it is a "skeleton" and i find it a little overkill comparing to the very simple MDI model of WinForms but i am willing to give it a try. I'll get back soon.